# Uncaught Reference Error, Javascript w/ object constructor instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object

Cannot create instances of object constructors from my Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}

persons = ['a']

});
```

The file is loading, in the Chrome JS console there is no problem calling the persons array, it exists in scope.

However,

```
var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
```

gives

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined
```

Pasting the Person constructor and then the myFather instance in the Chrome JS console works fine. There is something I am not doing right/don't understand.

Comment: If you're trying to create a new instance of `Person` outside of `document.ready` argument function, then the error occurs, `Person` is local to that argument function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope

Comment: You should probably define `Person` constructor **outside** of document.ready, and then use the constructor **inside** document.ready

Comment: Ah okay, I see, thanks. So I am able to console.log(myFather) within the file inside document.ready. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because you're declaring `Person` constructor inside `$(document).ready`, and you're using it outside. `Person` constructor would be local to the callback of `$(document).ready`. Declare `Person` constructor outside of the `$(document).ready`, but use it inside:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}

var persons = ['a'];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
  console.log(myFather);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a best practice for the kinds of things to include in $(document).ready(function() and things to put outside of it?

Comment: @learner2 Yes, put everything inside the  `$(document).ready(function() {...})`. The only situation you'd need a global variable is when you need cross-window scripting.